# jQuery: trigger keypress function on entire document but not inside inputs and textareas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I have this …

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if ( e.keyCode === 119 ) // w
            doSomething();
    });
```

Wo when pressing "w" on my document the `doSomething()` function fires. How can I prevent it from firing when I'm currently typing (in focus) in an `input` field or `textarea`?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You'll have to filter out the elements after the event and not in the selector, like this

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    var tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if ( e.which === 119 && tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') 
        doSomething();
});
```

this checks the tagname of the `event.target`, the element the event originated from, and only fires the function if the event did not originate from an input or textarea.

Comment: You saved me.
I used this from down answer:

       if (jQuery(e.target).is('input, textarea, select')) {
             return;   
       }

Comment: Why not use `e.key` instead of `e.which`?

Comment: @ElliotSchep - Because I wrote this in 2012, when `e.key` didn't exist, and jQuery normalized `e.which`

Comment: Hehe, well great job then

Answer (score 13):

If your event handler is bound to `document`, the event will have already been raised on the input element and bubbled up to the html element, so you will have to handle the exclusion within the code for the handler itself. The alternative is specifically binding a second handler for the input elements which prevents the event from bubbling, but that is probably not the right approach.

[**Code demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qESht/2/)

```
$(function() {
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('input, textarea')) {
            return;   
        }
        if (e.which === 119) doSomething();
    });
});​
```

p.s. you can have a look at the [jQuery event object documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) to see what properties it exposes.

Answer (score 6):

In jQuery, `e.which` is the normalized property, not `e.keyCode`.

To check if you are not in an input you can check the `document.activeElement`:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 119 && !$(document.activeElement).is(":input,[contenteditable]")) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/pxCS2/1/

Comment: Are you sure there is such a thing as an `':input'` pseudo-selector? I haven't been able to find a reference for this.

Comment: Warning: `<button>` is considered an `:input`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and perfect solution is:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 119 && !$(':focus').length) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

Comment: As your code is currently written, it filters too much. Anchors by default can get focus. Also, anything with a tabindex. So, this isn't the best solution for handling keyboard shortcuts on a web page where the keyboard may be used to navigate around the web page. http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/pp9e9/