# Javascript onkeydown/up

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I would like to know how I use `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` event in javscript correctly with an event listener. I want the event to listen when you just press in the website, not in a text field.

I don't know exactly how the script would look like but hopefully you understand what I want to do.
**I figured the code would look something like this:**

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', 'keyup', function(event) {
if(event.keyCode == 65){
    gas1();
}});
```

Sorry for being so unclear, trying my best to explain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: trigger keypress function on entire document but not inside inputs and textareas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807944/jquery-trigger-keypress-function-on-entire-document-but-not-inside-inputs-and-t)

Comment: for keydown event: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp

Comment: for keyup event: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

Answer (score 5):

Look an example I prepared in jsfiddle:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    console.log(event.key);
});
```

Simply add a listener to the whole document and check for the "key" in the event object you receive in the callback

[keydown event test](https://jsfiddle.net/g8f88ary/)

Answer (score 1):

Try Implementing this

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 65){
        gas1();
    }
}
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 65){
        gas1();
    }
}
```

But if you want to call a function gas1() only once on keypress just use keydown only.

Answer (score 1):

You can't aggregate two events on a single `document.addEventListener`. The first parameter is the name of the event, and the second a listener function called when it's fired.

Create two handlers, one for `keyup` and one for `keydown`, or use just `keypress` instead for this.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for checking KeyUp and KeyDown press on HTML page.

**Note** :Arrow keys are only triggered by onkeydown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode=="38")
     console.log("Up key pressed");
    else if(event.keyCode=="40")
        console.log("Down key pressed");
   };  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Above code is tested on system working fine.

**Note** :Try testing while your focus should be in Result area to print output on console.

Answer (score 0):

```
function defw(){
     for(var i =0; i < 10; i+= 1) {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      document.getElementsByTagName('section')[0].appendChild(div);
      }
 }

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    var ekey = event.keyCode
    if( 69 === ekey ) {
       defw();
    }
});
```

**This example is to make 10 `DIVS` calling the function `defw()`**
1. SAVE the event.keyCode in a variable 
2. THe value 69 is the keyboard letter e in your KEYBOARD

**HERE IS THE LINK [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/alexpixel/pen/bwpmQZ)**